# Replicating R installation

Tags: r

I run R jobs on multiple Ubuntu machines. I have written several R packages for my projects. I would like to develop & compile all the packages on one development machine and then replicate the installation to all production machines.

How can I replicate the R installation of development machine to the production machine without distributing the package source codes and compiling it on every machine. This will make sure that all machines are running the same code.

Comment: Once you have build your R packages on the development machine you can copy the `.tar.gz` source package to each machine and from R do `install.packages()`. If you are not asking about how to install R packages, please edit your question to clarify your intent.

Comment: If you want a fully reproducible R environment on each machine that won't interfere with your system installation, check out [rocker](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker) which provides various docker images for different R computing environments.